# Magento1.9 : My block is not calling in shell script

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, shell, mage-shell

My block is not calling in shell script.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
require_once 'abstract.php';
class Mage_Shell_ReportMail extends Mage_Shell_Abstract{
    public function run(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/template')->setTemplate('salesreport.phtml')->toHtml();
    }
}

$shell = new Mage_Shell_ReportMail();
$shell->run();

?>
```

Comment: it seems block not able to take template path correctly. I kept template in frontend side and it is working, however when I kept it in adminhtml it is not calling...

Comment: `Mage::getDesign()->setArea('adminhtml');` added this line after setting store and it is working..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems block was not taking correct template area and it was trying to find file in frontend area instead adminhtml.

Need to define template area for adminhtml so it will call from correct path.

```
 Mage::getDesign()->setArea('adminhtml');
```